# Differential Equation: Solve for P Analytically

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In response to this thread, [Advanced Algebraic Equation - Solve for P](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606272/advanced-algebraic-equation-solve-for-p), I noticed that the answer given was numerically approximated. Now my question is, if one is given the Differential Equation dP/dT = KP(P-K)(L-P), where K and L are constants, is it possible to analytically find a solution only in terms of P. The answer given assumed that L > K > 0, but what if it was never specified that this had to be the case. What if all that was stated was that L and K were unequal constants? How would one go about solving the equation then?

Comment: @Moo The user's solution assume that P was somewhere in the neighborhood between (K,L) and that L > K > 0. Aside from that, Wolfram only solved for K, but not P, and it assumed that K(T) was a function as opposed to a constant.

Answer (score 1):

The equation

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{dP}{dT}=-KP(P-K)(P-L)
\end{equation}

is easily solved for $T$ in terms of $P$ if that is the meaning of the question, since we have

\begin{align}
-K\dfrac{dT}{dP}&=\dfrac{1}{P(P-K)(P-L)}\\
                &=\dfrac{\frac{1}{KL}}{P}+\dfrac{\frac{1}{K(K-L)}}{P-K}+\dfrac{\frac{1}{L(L-K)}}{P-L}
\end{align}

So we have

\begin{equation}
e^{-KT}+C=P^{\frac{1}{KL}}(P-K)^{\frac{1}{K(K-L)}}(P-L)^{\frac{1}{L(L-K)}}
\end{equation}

Comment: How could one solve for P from there?